# Are deferred functions called when calling log.Fatalln?

Tags: go, exception-safety

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "…")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer db.Close()

tpl, err := template.ParseGlob("")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

If `template.ParseGlob("")` returns an error, is `db.Close()` still being called?

Comment: No. If you need deferred functions running, use `log.Panicln`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, the deferred functions aren't run.

Here's the description of [log.Fatal](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) :

> Fatal is equivalent to Print() followed by a call to os.Exit(1).

`log.Fatal` calls `os.Exit`, whose description is [here](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) :

> Exit causes the current program to exit with the given status code.
>   Conventionally, code zero indicates success, non-zero an error. The
>   program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.

[Demonstration](http://play.golang.org/p/fDQpYlV6DY)

If you really need to properly close resources or do some tasks before the program finishes, then don't use `log.Fatal`.

Comment: If calling `log.Fatalln` in `main()`, you could instead call `log.Println` followed by `return`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want deferred functions to be considered use "log.Panic", "log.Panicf" or "log.Panicln"